# How to specify download path for youtube-dl on Windows?

Tags: windows, youtube-dl

I have created `config.txt` in `~\AppData\Roaming\youtube-dl\`. When using `-o ~%(title)s.%(ext)s` command the downloaded files are saved to `C:\Users`. I may want to save the files to the Windows' downloads folder instead. When I use `-o ~\Downloads\%(title)s.%(ext)s` in `config.txt` "Downloads" is added to the filename and the files are still saved in `Users` folder.

Comment: Is the question OS-agnostic?

Comment: @Ramhound: What? https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/ "is not platform specific".

Comment: Your question is though....

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, but I considered changing my question to cater all OS'. Perhaps I'll add locations for Linux and Mac.

Comment: You shouldn't expand the scope of this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can't use  the home directory shortcut `~` on Windows. You have to specify the full path, such as `C:/Users/user/Downloads/`.
- Use `/` instead of `\`.
- [According to documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template-examples) using `"` instead of `'` may be necessary on Windows.

example command:

```
-o "C:/Users/user/Downloads/youtube-dl/%(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

Answer (score -1):

I had some issues with it, too. Remember, you have to put the -o command at the end in Windows to work. This is how I got mine to work.